# Terraform unquoted resource for Terraform 0.11

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform 0.11 for a custom module implementation of terraform-aws-provider. Inside the module there are a lot of unquoted resource value assignments that make me confused since they are not working.

This is the sample module code that I am using

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
  name   = example_policy
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}
```

In the official terraform documentation, it was given with interpolation around the value to become

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
  name   = "example_policy"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json}"
}
```

from: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html

When I tried to do `terraform get`  the following error message came up:

> `Unknown token: 39:24 IDENT data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json`

and when I tried to use terraform 0.12, it managed to fetch it correctly.

Is this unquoted resource value exclusive to terraform > v0.12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Terraform 0.11 requires that all references look like string interpolations (like your second example). Terraform 0.12 added support for [first-class expressions](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#first-class-expressions) which let you reference variables outside of strings (like your first example).

The docs also include an example of the newer, cleaner syntax:

```
# Old 0.11 example
tags = "${merge(map("Name", "example"), var.common_tags)}"

# Updated 0.12 example
tags = merge({ Name = "example" }, var.common_tags)
```